# How to access object inside array of previous backend call while doing sequential call?

Tags: krakend

I have one endpoint in krakenD which has two backends to call in sequential and second call is dependent on first one response.

First call response:

```json
{
          "banners": {
            "hero_banner_position": 4,
            "hero_banners": [
              {
                "banner_url": "XXX",
                "id": "banner-id",
                "name": "banner_8xWd2",
                "position": 1
              }
            ]
}
```

In my second call I want to access id of the first item inside hero_banners but it's not working. I tried it using `resp0_banners.hero_banners.0.id` but it did not work.

I need help to make it work or alternative solution

Comment: Its mentioned in docs that "You cannot access nested objects inside arrays or collections, they must be objects." In order to use nested object's property, you need to change your "first backend response".